# Issue with timestamp field while using SQOOP

Tags: oracle, sqoop

An extra space is added before the milliseconds while timestamp field is being ingested for eg. 05-OCT-17 03.39.02.689000000 AM is ingested as
 2017-10-5 3:39:2. 689000000. Using Oracle as the source,parquet format as the format for storing the data in HDFS.

Any suggestions on how it can be avoided.

Comment: You can use --map-column-java or --map-column-hive in sqoop import

Comment: @vinayak_narune the issue is with the extra space after seconds.like 2017-10-5 3:39:2.68900000 is ingested as 2017-10-5 3:39:2.(space) 68900000

Comment: Can you give the sqoop statement used.